# Create ViewObject as placeholder for form parameters

Tags: forms, jsf-2, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

## Background

Trying to create a [ViewObject](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/web.111230/e16182/bcquerying.htm#ADFFD237) (using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3) that can be dropped on a page to create a form such as:

---

[image: Form with no inputs]

---

The form parameters must be submitted to a custom reporting framework. In the ViewObject, certain attributes must be linked to List-of-Value selectors, or have its data type picked up from the ViewObject automatically. The developer should be able to drag-and-drop the ViewObject to create a functional form.

This would allow the form to perform input validation using the ViewObject, and allow List-of-Value objects to be used as well.

## Problem

There is no entity that backs the ViewObject. There is no SQL that drives the ViewObject. The ViewObject doesn't really need programmatic access, nor is it a static list. It is simply meant to be a container for parameters that can be subjected to validation rules. When a developer drops such a ViewObject on the form, it creates a form with no visible input fields:

---

[image: Form with inputs]

---

The code behind the scenes resembles:

```
  <af:inputText value="#{bindings.ManagementCentre.inputValue}"
                label="#{bindings.ManagementCentre.hints.label}"
                required="#{bindings.ManagementCentre.hints.mandatory}"
                columns="#{bindings.ManagementCentre.hints.displayWidth}"
                maximumLength="#{bindings.ManagementCentre.hints.precision}"
                shortDesc="#{bindings.ManagementCentre.hints.tooltip}"
                id="report_P_MANAGEMENT_CENTRE">
  </af:inputText>
  <af:inputText value="#{bindings.ClinicServiceCentreName.inputValue}"
                label="#{bindings.ClinicServiceCentreName.hints.label}"
                required="#{bindings.ClinicServiceCentreName.hints.mandatory}"
                columns="#{bindings.ClinicServiceCentreName.hints.displayWidth}"
                maximumLength="#{bindings.ClinicServiceCentreName.hints.precision}"
                shortDesc="#{bindings.ClinicServiceCentreName.hints.tooltip}"
                id="report_P_CLINIC_SERVICE_CENTRE">
    <f:validator binding="#{bindings.ClinicServiceCentreName.validator}"/>
    </af:inputText>
```

The code for the submit button runs a managed bean to extract the form parameters and pass them into the report (via a report framework):

```
  <af:commandButton text="Run Report" id="submitReport">
    <af:fileDownloadActionListener method="#{reportBean.run}" />
  </af:commandButton>
```

## Question

How do you create such a ViewObject that can perform validation but does not need to be backed by a data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

You have to:

- Create a view object to be programmatic, with the desired attributes.
- Configure the view object with validation rules.
- Configure the Application Module.
- Create the web page form.
- Update the page binding to create a new row.

## Create View Object

Create the view object as follows:

1. Type <kbd>Control+n</kbd> to open the **New Gallery**.
2. Search for and select **View Object**.
3. Click **OK**.
4. Set **Package**, **Name**, and **Display Name** appropriately.
5. Set **Data Source** to **Programmatic**.
6. Click **Next**.
7. Click **New** and provide a meaningful attribute name.
8. Click **OK**.
9. Add the remaining attributes.
10. Click **Next**.
11. Set **Updatable** to **Always** for all attributes.
12. Set **Type** to the appropriate data type.
13. Click **Finish**.

## Configure Validation Rules

Configure the validation rules as follows:

1. Click the **Attributes** finger tab.
2. Select the desired attribute.
3. Click the **Validation Rules** tab.
4. Click the **+** icon within the **Validation Rules** section.
5. Set the **Rule Definition** as required.
6. Set the **Error Message** as required.
7. Repeat to add as many validation rules as necessary.

At this point a view object has been configured and the **List of Values** tab can be used to reference query-based LOVs.

## Configure Application Module

Configure the application module as follows:

1. Double click the application's application module.
2. Select the **Data Model** finger tab.
3. Shuttle the view object from **Available View Objects** to **Data Model**.
4. Remove the **1** suffix.
5. Save the application.

Note: If the view object is not visible, restart JDeveloper.

## Create Web Page Form

Create a web page for the form as follows:

1. Create a new JSF page for the view object.
2. Refresh the **Data Controls** to see the view object instance.
3. Drag and drop the view object onto the page.
4. Select **Form » ADF Form**.
5. Check **Include Submit Button**.
6. Click **OK**.

The web page is created.

## Update Page Binding

The attributes for the view object cannot be changed unless there is a "row" created for the view object instance. Creating this in-memory row must happen before the page content is displayed. Accomplish this as follows:

1. Expand the Data Controls to reveal the view object's **Operations**.
2. Drag **Create** into the footer facet.
3. Select **ADF Button**.
4. Right-click on the page.
5. Select **Go to Page Definition**.
6. Click **+** beside **Executables**.
7. Select **invokeAction**.
8. Click **OK**.
9. Set **id** to: create
10. Set **Binds** to: Create
11. Click OK.
12. Set Refresh to: **prepareModelIfNeeded**
13. Save all.

Validation is applied and data-driven LOVs can be used.

Remove the "Create" button.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a simple Java class with a method that accepts two parameters.
Expose the Java class as a data control and then drag it into your page to create the parameter form.

You can then add LOVs etc for field.
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/adding_lov_to_non_database